# Javascript comparing mouse click to xy to that of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouse, coordinates

I am trying to get the x and y of an html button to that of a mouseclick by the user, I am doing this as follows:

```
function buttonPressed(event, id){
var mainEvent = event ? event : window.event;
var mousex=event.clientX;
var mousey=mainEvent.screenY;
var y= $('#'+id).position();
var x= document.getElementById(id).offsetLeft;

console.log(y);
console.log(mousey);
```

This shows 2 different ways to get these value of both the button and the mouse (event.clientX,mainEvent.screenY,$('#'+id).position()(uses jquery),and offsetLeft).
However none of these techniques seem to work as I would like them to as the values do not line up ie when I click on the top left of the button the values are not the same or even similar. Additionally it seems like the difference changes, for example: if I have a button top left and one top right on the top left the values may differ by 100, whereas the bottom they will differ by -100. How can I acheive what I am wanting (to be able to compare the mousex and the button x)?

Answer (score 0):

client X/Y  Mouse pointer X/Y coordinate relative to window

offset X/Y  Mouse pointer X/Y coordinate relative to element that fired the event

screen X/Y      Relative to the top left of the physical screen/monitor

Thats why you are getting difference here

```
var mousex=event.clientX;
var mousey=mainEvent.screenY;
```

Use clientX for both

Comment: following your advice they still dont correlate